# Webpack switching between style-loader and extract-text-webpack-plugin

Tags: javascript, css, webpack, webpack-dev-server, hot-module-replacement

I have development and production webpack configurations where I switch between using `style-loader` and `extract-text-webpack-plugin` to bundle CSS, respectively.  This is because my development config uses hot module replacement, and thus requires inline-styles, while my production config does not.

However, upon switching from production to development, I've noticed that the extracted `main.css` left over from my production webpack build is **overriding** the inline styles of my `style-loader`.  This means that hot reloading does not work on CSS changes.

First, shouldn't my inline styles override my external `main.css` stylesheet, so why is this occurring?  Second, if this is expected behavior, what is the general convention for dealing with this?  Should I use some webpack "cleaning" plugin to remove `main.css` in my development config?

Comment: There are a number of reasons for why your main.css is overriding your inline styles. Could you post a sample of the main.css for analysis?

Comment: I second that. We need a sample of a CSS class in main.css that is overriding the inline-style. You should also using a procedure to clean your directories.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
const env = require('./env.json');

var conf = {

    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.ts', '.js'],
        root: __dirname,
        modulesDirectories: ['node_modules']
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            //Some common Loaders Here
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: 'source-map-loader',
                exclude: [
                    'node_modules/rxjs'
                ]
            }

        ],
        loaders: [{
            test: /\.ts$/,
            loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader'
        }],
    },
    plugins: [
        //Some common plugins Here ,
    ],
    output: {
        path: 'src',
        filename: '[name].bundle.js',
        sourceMapFilename: '[name].bundle.map',
        //chunkFilename: '[id].[chunkhash].chunk.js'
    }
};

if (env.dev) {
    conf.module.rules.push({
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
            fallback: "style-loader",
            use: "css-loader"
        })
    });
    conf.plugins.push(new ExtractTextPlugin("styles.css"));

} else {

    conf.module.rules.push({
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [{
                loader: "style-loader"
            },
            {
                loader: "css-loader"
            }
        ]
    });


}

module.exports = conf;
```